# Need help building a Telegram web app using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, telegram-bot

I have created a Telegram bot that features an inline keyboard whereby a user can enter a code. See GIF 1 below. The message text is updated as you tap the keyboard buttons so that you can see all the digits you have entered. The web app behind this is a Google Apps Script project. I'm enclosing my code below.

Everything works pretty well as long as you go slow, waiting for the text to update before you tap the next button. But as you speed up a bit, there are multiple instances of the web app running concurrently, trying to update the same message text which results in havoc. See GIF 2 below.

The desired behavior I'm aiming for is for the message text to update correctly no matter how fast I go at tapping the buttons. I do need each doPost instance to complete before the next one runs. Or, that's what I think the good plan is.

Please, help me figure this out.

```
function doPost(e) {
  
  var contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  
  var mes_id = contents.callback_query.message.message_id;
    
  var user_input = contents.callback_query.data;
    
  var text_field = contents.callback_query.message.text;
    
  var inline_keyboard = contents.callback_query.message.reply_markup;   
    
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "/answerCallbackQuery?callback_query_id=" + String(contents.callback_query.id)); 
    
  text_field = text_field + ' ' + user_input;
 
  var keydata = {
        method: "post",
        payload: {
          method: "editMessageText",
          chat_id: String(mychat_id),
          message_id: mes_id,
          text: text_field,
          parse_mode: "HTML",
          reply_markup: JSON.stringify(inline_keyboard)
        }
      }
        
UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + token + '/', keydata); 
        
}
```

[image: tapping slowly]

[image: tapping faster]

Comment: Do you have access to something like RxJS in your project? This would simplify asynchronous operations like this

Comment: @BobbyTables, I don't think so. This is a Google Apps Script project.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment i gather that there is no asynchronicity (no async/await nor promises) in Google Apps Script.

This pseudocode might work, it puts new requests on a queue if theres a current one running - and then process them when the previous is done  (it hurts my brain to not having async operations)

```
let processing = false;
let queue = [];

doPost() {
   if (!processing) {
     // Mark that were running a request (and dont run more at the same time)
     processing = true;

    [ HERE GOES YOUR CURRENT CODE ]

     // Now the request is done, lets see if theres more in the queue
     processing = false;
     if (queue.lenght > 0) {
       doPost(queue.pop()); // Lets process the next request
     }
   } else {
     // Another request is processing, so put this on the queue
     queue.push(e);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try. And sorry, I misunderstood your question. There definitely is async/await and promises in Google Apps Script. The problem is I still can't wrap my brain around how to use these. I would very much appreciate it if you gave me a clue.

Comment: Unfortunately im not familiar enough with GAS to whip up a soluiton for you. Seems UrlFetchApp.fetch() is synchronous, and hence you need to wrap it in a promise (this would remove the boolean 'processing' from the code above. Here you can see someone wrapping it: https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-javascript/issues/566#issuecomment-584537819

Comment: Sorry, I tried and I can't seem to understand how the code above should work. The way I see it, every time an inline keyboard key is tapped a new separate instance of function doPost(e) is invoked. So how is the queue array supposed to survive once a particular doPost instance ends? And how is the array going to be accessible by further instances of doPost(e)?

Comment: So you have no greater scope than doPost()? Is there any session variables or similar?  As i mentioned, im not familiar with GAS - i saw the JavaScript tag and took a stab =)

Comment: Oh, got it. Yeah, there's scriptProperties, for example, that allows to store string variables that can be accessed by various instances of the script. And there's Google Sheets, of course, where you can store anything. The downside is that storing and retrieving makes things way too slow. There's gonna be seconds between the actual tap on a key and when the digit finally appears. So, I was just looking for an elegant way to do things within one instance of doPost.